# Почему французских королей принято называть ЛюдОвиками?

Tags: этимология, история

Ударение для французского явно нехарактерное.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Латинское. По-французски они все звались Луями. Исходно это одно и тоже имя, "среднее" между ними - итальянское Луиджи.

Традиция использовать латинизированный вариант имени была характерна не только для французов. Даже германцы его не избежали, латинскими вариантами имен пользовались монархи Священной Римской империи и Австро-Венгрии. Вообще дело объясняется, видимо,  тем, что в те времена в качестве единого языка общения использовалась латынь, особенно в дипломатии. Все французские Луи стали Людовиками, а Шарли - Карлами.

Самое интересное, что современное французское имя ЛюдовИк, вошедшее в моду уже после эпохи "номерных" Людовиков, считается во Франции *другим* именем.

Answer (score 0):

Да ж это не латынь вообще, это русское переложение немецкого  Ludwig, скорее кличка чем имя, поскольку корешок wig означает парик, в английском Whigs - виги, они на своем флаге парик таскали в качестве бунчука. ну и влияние польского, ludowe.